# How can I customize interface and removing some of tools from a toolbar

Tags: qgis, user-interface

I would like to customize the interface based on essential tools for a project in qgis. Is there a way to remove some of tools from toolbar, for example in Map Navigation Toolbar I want to keep only zoom in, zoom out and pan and I do not need zoom to extend or zoom to selection and the others?

[image]

Comment: You mean https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#customization ?

Comment: for example in Map Navigation Toolbar I want to keep only zoom in, zoom out and pan and I do not need zoom to extend or zoom to selection.

Comment: for a **new** custom toolbar, there is this [plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/CustomToolBar/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works very well.